# What is the exact definition/meaning of Users, Sessions and Page Views in Google Analytics report?

Tags: google-analytics

As the subject says, I'd like to know what is the exact definition of these 3 terms:

- Users
- Sessions
- Page Views

And why is there Pages/Session, not Pages/User?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Users:** the number of visitors that have at least 1 session on your website.
If the same person visits your website several times a month, it is registered as 1 user.
Uniqueness here is not defined by the individual, but by his computer/browser, when a person visits for the first time, a user ID is created as a cookie for that specific user. So if the same user visits from another computer, it is registered as another user in GA.
**cookie expiration:** 2 years. It resets automatically every time a user visits a page.
......
**Sessions:** the number of times visitors are engaged on your website.
If the same person visits your website 3 times a day, with few hours in between, it is registered as 3 sessions.
a cookie is created when a person first visits your website, it is counted as 1 session as long as the cookie is active.
**cookie expiration:** 30 minutes. It resets automatically every time a user makes an action. It also expires at midnight 12 am.
......
**Page Views:** the total number of pages people visited on your website.
If a user clicks multiple times on one page, each time is counted as a visit. It also applies if a person refresh the page.
......
I am not exactly sure why there is Pages/Session but not Pages/User.
This is how you can calculate Pages per User manually:
**Pageviews / users = Pages per User

4,220,773 / 1,915,234 = 2.20 Pages/User on average**

......
Check this article for in-depth explanation: [What Is The Difference Between Sessions, Users, And Pageviews?](https://medium.com/@digitalisesmartly/what-is-the-difference-between-sessions-users-and-pageviews-6a6eb6018d10)